# Instance of a structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, constructor, instance

I've been looking into this issue for 2 days, but no luck.

I have the following struct predefined

```
struct Motor : Port {
Motor(port_t port) : Port(port) {}
void moveAtVelocity(int velocity) { move_at_velocity(m_port, velocity); }
....
};
```

I've then tried to call an instance of the struct

```
Motor M;
```

And I'm getting

```
Error: No matching function for call to Motor::Motor()
Note: Candidates are Motor::Motor(port_t)
```

How do I call an instance so for example I can use the following method

```
moveAtVelocity(..);
```

I know I messed up between classes and structures and constructors and destructors; The thing is that I can't find a proper tutorial, extra kudos if you can link one for me.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s right; what you should have instead is:

```
Motor M(123);
```

(where 123 is a port).

When you just say `Motor M;`, the compiler attempts to construct this object by calling a parameterless constructor. You don’t have any defined. You can, however, just pass the required parameter like I’ve shown above.

An alternative solution is, of course, to just add a parameterless constructor, but this requires your base class, `Port`, to have one too, or for you to pass a fixed value:

```
Motor() : Port(123) {}  // fixed value
Motor() {} // assumes Port has a parameterless constructor
```

Answer (score 2):

`Motor` has a constructor that takes one argument, `port_t`, so no default constructor is generated (one with no arguments). Try:

```
Motor M(14); // where 14 is a guess by me at what a `port_t` is.
```

If there is sensible default value for `port_t` you could either add a default constructor to `Motor`:

```
struct Motor : Port {
    Motor() : Port(14) {}
    Motor(port_t port) : Port(port) {}
    void moveAtVelocity(int velocity) { move_at_velocity(m_port, velocity); }
    ....
};
```

or specify a default value for parameter in the current constructor:

```
struct Motor : Port {
    Motor(port_t port = 14) : Port(port) {}
    void moveAtVelocity(int velocity) { move_at_velocity(m_port, velocity); }
    ....
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that there could be a tutorial that didn't mention this.
There aren't really any struct's in C++.  The keyword `struct` defines a
class type, exactly like the keyword `class`.  The only differences are
1) when you use the keyword `struct`, you start out `public`; and when
you use the keyword `class`, you start out `private`; and 2) inheritance
is by default `public` with `struct`, and `private` with `class`.  So:

```
struct Motor : Port
{
    Motor( port_t port ) : Port( port ) {}
    //  ...
};
```

is exactly the same as:

```
class Motor : public Port
{
public:
    Motor( port_t port ) : Port( port ) {}
    //  ...
};
```

And since you've provided a constructor, the compiler doesn't generate a
default constructor.